# Converting day count to date time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've seen many examples of the reverse (date time --> day count), but can't seem to figure out how to convert day counts to date times.

I have a df that looks like this:

```
day person var
1   1      a
2   1      b
3   1      a
1   2      b
2   2      b
3   2      b
1   3      a
2   3      a
3   3      b
............
180 1      b
```

How would I convert the day variable to a date time, assuming day=1 equates to datetime=01/01/2019?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure pandas solution:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')
df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['day']-1, unit='D') + start_date
```

output:

```
   day  person var       date
0    1       1   a 2019-01-01
1    2       1   b 2019-01-02
2    3       1   a 2019-01-03
3    1       2   b 2019-01-01
4    2       2   b 2019-01-02
5    3       2   b 2019-01-03
6    1       3   a 2019-01-01
7    2       3   a 2019-01-02
8    3       3   b 2019-01-03
```

Comment: Nice, but you have to subtract 1 from the `day` column, or use a different `start_date`.

Comment: That's true @JanChristophTerasa

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a more "pandasy" solution, but pure Python will probably do:

```
import datetime

ref = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
dates = [ref + datetime.timedelta(days=d-1) for d in df['day']]
df['date'] = dates # adds a new column 'date' to the dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
>>> later = date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
>>> later
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 0, 0)
```